# Error : expected primary-expression before 'int' and many similar errors like this in the code

Tags: c++

PS: I'm a beginner.
The full code I was trying is as follows: [this_is_the_tree_I_Was_trying_to_code_up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlHPc.jpg)
Errors were on line 30,50,63,74 and 82, like on:

line 30: expected primary-expression before 'int';expected primary-expression before 'char';
line 50: expected primary-expression before 'int';expected primary-expression before 'char';
line 63: expected primary-expression before 'int';expected primary-expression before 'char';
line 74: expected primary-expression before 'int';expected primary-expression before 'char';expected primary-expression before 'int';
line 82: expected primary-expression before 'int';expected primary-expression before 'char';expected primary-expression before 'int';

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class staff{
protected:
    int code;
    char *name;
public:
    staff(){}
    staff(int code1,char *name1){
        code=code1;
        int length;
        length=strlen(name1);
        name=new char[length+1];
        strcpy(name,name1);
    }
    void display(){
        cout<<"Staff code is: "<<code<<"\n";
        cout<<"Name is: "<<name<<"\n";
    }
};
class teacher:public staff{
protected:
    char *subject;
    char *publication;
public:
    teacher(){}
    teacher(int code1,char *name1,char *sub1,char *pub1):
        staff(int code1,char *name1){                      //line 30
        int len1,len2;
        len1=strlen(sub1);
        len2=strlen(pub1);
        subject=new char[len1+1];
        publication=new char[len2+1];
        strcpy(subject,sub1);
        strcpy(publication,pub1);
    }
    void display_t(){
        cout<<"Subject is: "<<subject<<"\n";
        cout<<"Publication is: "<<publication<<"\n";
    }
};
class officer:public staff{
protected:
    char grade;
public:
    officer(){}
    officer(int code1,char *name1,char grd1):
        staff(int code1,char *name1){                       //line 50
        grade=grd1;
    }
    void display_o(){
        cout<<"Grade is: "<<grade;
    }
};
class typist:public staff{
protected:
    int speed;
public:
    typist(){}
    typist(int code1,char *name1,int spd):
        staff(int code1,char *name1){                         //line 63
        speed=spd;
    }
    void display_typ(){
        cout<<"Speed is: "<<speed<<"\n";
    }
};
class regular:public typist{
public:
    regular(){}
    regular(int code1,char *name1,int spd):
        typist(int code1,char *name1,int spd){}            //line 74
};
class casual:public typist{
protected:
    float dailywage;
public:
    casual(){}
    casual(float wage,int code1,char *name1,int spd):
        typist(int code1,char *name1,int spd){             //line 82
        dailywage=wage;
    }
    void display_c(){
        cout<<"Daily wage of casual typists are: "<<dailywage<<"\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    casual c1;
    c1=casual(2100.05,002,"Ganesh",50);
    c1.display();
    //c1.display_t();
    c1.display_typ();
    //c1.display_o();
    c1.display_c();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We can't see line numbers. Please add the error message as a comment next to the line that has an error.

Comment: Added the line  numbers as comments rightwards the code. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better.

Comment: Thank you @cigien ,I was able to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
teacher(int code1,char *name1,char *sub1,char *pub1):
        staff(int code1,char *name1) {
```

you are using the wrong syntax to call the base class constructor. You need to pass along only the variables, not the types.

This is how to write it correctly:

```
teacher(int code1,char *name1,char *sub1,char *pub1):
        staff(code1, name1) {
```

All your other errors are caused by the same mistake, so you'll need to do this for all your derived classes' constructors.